# Company name is wrong in the Trademark Guidelines

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange, legal, trademark

The [Trademark Guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name
>
> There is some confusion around the proper use and context of the Stack Exchange name. Here are some guidelines:
>
> **Stack Exchange Inc.** is the official name of the company.

I thought it was now Stack Overflow?

Comment: No, the official name (i.e. the legal name) **is** Stack Exchange Inc. - we do call ourselves Stack Overflow for the day-to-day.

Comment: @Oded Ahh, I thought that was the name change! My mistake!

Comment: No worries - it can be confusing :)